# Boost installation issue in windows

Tags: python, c++, gcc, boost

I am installing boost_1_60_0 based on directions given in official website for Windows.

- http://www.boost.org/users/download/

Below is the command I am running to install boost for my project in C++.

```
boost_1_60_0>b2 -j8 --toolset=gcc  --build-dir=C:\mycode\src\threadsupport\boost_1_60_0\build  --build-type=complete  stage
```

This gives me some Python-related error even though I have installed Python 2.7.11.

Below are the error logs:

```
boost_1_60_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\python\build\gcc-mingw-4.8.1\release\numeric.o:numeric.cpp:(.text+0x20f9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyInt_FromLong'
boost_1_60_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\python\build\gcc-mingw-4.8.1\release\numeric.o:numeric.cpp:(.text+0x2138): undefined reference to `_imp__PyEval_CallFunction'
boost_1_60_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\python\build\gcc-mingw-4.8.1\release\numeric.o:numeric.cpp:(.text+0x228b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_FromStringAndSize'
boost_1_60_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\python\build\gcc-mingw-4.8.1\release\numeric.o:numeric.cpp:(.text+0x22ad): undefined reference to `_imp__PyImport_Import'
```

There are a lot of similar type of errors coming. Any help regarding this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you run `bootstrap.bat mingw` before calling `b2`?

Comment: I just run `b2 toolset=gcc link=shared threading=multi --build-type=complete stage` after `bootstrap.bat mingw` and I haven't had a problem on any version of `boost` on `Windows 7` or `Windows 10`. I don;t use python, so that could be an issue or it may be syntax of your command. I don;t think that `toolset=gcc` shoud have `--` in front of it.

Comment: @kenba : I am using same command what you have suggested.

Comment: @kenba: While debugging errors I found below errors:
Any feedback about it would be much appreciated:
C:\boost\boost_1_60_0/libs/coroutine/src/detail/coroutine_context.cpp:71: undefined reference to `_imp__jump_fcontext'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @kenba: still getting the same error :(

Comment: Is the directory containing `mingw` and it's associated tools in your `PATH`?

Comment: @kenba: mingw is already present and is added in system path as well,
though the error still persists but under stage/lib libraries are generated.
Since i needed threading and socket libs for my project which are present under stage/lib, hence closing the question.

Comment: @kenba: Thanks for your support anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Had a lot of problems as well, these simple steps fixed it for me.

Step1:

```
bootstrap.bat
```

Step2:

```
b2 toolset=msvc link=shared threading=multi --build-type=complete stage
```